# jetpack compose removing elements from list of text fields

Tags: android, kotlin, input, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

[image: list of text fields].

I want my code to remove elements from list of text fields properly.
Each element has an X button to remove it's text field.
If I start removing elements from the bottom it works but **it doesn't work for removing random elements**
**I want to use forEachIndexed for displaing the list**
Please help me with solving this problem. I've been trying to do this for some time but every trial is unsuccessful.

This is a piece of code that I've managed to write but removing elements doesn't work properly

```
val listOfWords = mutableStateListOf<String>()


@Composable
fun Main() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Text(
            text = "Words",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 4.dp),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
        )

            listOfWords.forEachIndexed { index, word ->
                Input(word, 30, "Word", 1,
                    {newWord ->
                        listOfWords[index] = newWord
                        Log.d("text ",word)
                    },
                    {
                        listOfWords.removeAt(index)
                    }
                )
            }

        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                listOfWords.add("")
            }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
                contentDescription = "Add"
            )
        }


    }
}

@Composable
fun Input(
    word: String,
    maxChar: Int,
    label: String,
    maxLines: Int,
    onEdit: (word: String) -> (Unit),
    onRemove: () -> (Unit)
) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(word) }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp, 0.dp, 8.dp, 0.dp)
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.length <= maxChar) text = it
                onEdit(text)
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            label = { Text(label) },
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Edit, null)
            },
            trailingIcon = {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    onRemove()
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Clear,
                        contentDescription = "Back"
                    )
                }
            },
            maxLines = maxLines
        )

        Text(
            text = "${text.length} / $maxChar",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.caption,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(end = 16.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to try and do this? Show your code.

Comment: Use a Column with a Row for each element

Comment: @cliff2310 I updated my question so you can see what the problem is.

Comment: Your code is working for this question, if you have another problem (which is removing as you said), it should be another post or edit the entire question and title of this post while there is no accepted answers yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf(word) }
```

Without supplying a `key` to `Input's` `remember`, compose will not be able refresh/update your remaining `Input's` states during `Main's` `re-composition` every time an `Input` is removed.

You can use the `word` parameter as `key` for `remember` to `re-calculate` every composition pass (i.e when you add/remove or typed a value in the TextField), and your code should probably work as you expected.

```
var text by remember(word) { mutableStateOf(word) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the following instead?

```
listOfWords.forEachIndexed { index, word ->
    ... // rest of code
    {
        listOfWords.removeAt(index)
    }
```

Comment: your answer is useful because forEachIndexed is better for this, but is still doesn't work how I want. The problem is the list as a composable view doesn't refresh in the proper way. The very list contains correct values but it seems like compose removes always the last element (TextField) no matter what the index is.

Comment: I guess I did not see the issue correctly at first, someone else did though, still glad I was able to help somehow!